# How to post a list of all open positions in a visualforce page without using a Custom Controller?

Tags: visualforce, controller, controller-extension

We want to post all open positions (custom object) to a Visualforce page. I want to keep all the standard functionality of the standard controller, but only show  Positions with Status = "Open".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically, you can't do so in "pure" Visualforce (that is, without JavaScript or Apex to supplement the logic). Visualforce's list capabilities are rather limited; as soon as you hit 10,000 rows of unfiltered data, you would exceed limits. You can, however, choose to use [apex:remoteObjects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_remoteObjects.htm#!) if you wanted a client-side only experience, such as manually creating HTML, jQuery, Angular, etc.